# MERGE statement is not updating

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, merge

When executing the following on SQL Server, I would expect the NULL be updated with value 88888888 but it inserts a new row instead.
Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
USE tempdb;

CREATE TABLE TableA (ColA CHAR(8), ColB CHAR(8))
CREATE TABLE TableB (ColA CHAR(8), ColB CHAR(8))

INSERT INTO TableA VALUES  ( 'XXXXXXXX', NULL )
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES  ( 'XXXXXXXX', '88888888')

MERGE INTO TableB AS T
USING TableA AS S
ON T.ColA = S.ColA and T.ColB = S.ColB
WHEN MATCHED 
    THEN
      UPDATE
         SET T.ColA = S.ColA, T.ColB = S.ColB
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
    THEN
      INSERT (ColA, ColB) VALUES (S.ColA, S.ColB);

SELECT  * FROM    TableA
SELECT  * FROM    TableB

DROP TABLE TableA
DROP TABLE TableB
```

Many Thanks!
Best Regards,
Steve

Answer (score 5):

a) Tables are inherently unordered. Even if (as you seem to expect) the merge proceeded one row at a time (see `c` below), there's no reason it wouldn't see the row with both columns non-null before the row with a null `ColB`

b) Your `ON` clause specifies a match on both `ColA` and `ColB`. Both rows are different in at least one of these, so I'd expect neither row to match a row in `TableB`, and

c) SQL statements apply as if all rows are affected in parallel, at the same time. It doesn't process one row, and then move onto the next. So there's never an occasion where there's exactly one row in `TableB`.

Unfortunately, what you've posted is obviously a "toy" example, so I can't offer any recommendations for how to fix it - you've not told us what the real situation is, what the real data looks like, why you're using `MERGE`, etc.

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever, your comment is correct. It looks like I'm trying to do something which is not possible using the merge statement. It's seems like I'm going to need a cursor(...). Thanks for the hint!!

Answer (score 2):

```
MERGE INTO TableB AS T
USING TableA AS S
ON T.ColA = S.ColA 
WHEN MATCHED 
THEN
  UPDATE
     SET  T.ColB = S.ColB
```

Please remove this from join: **and T.ColB = S.ColB**.

And also you can remove **T.ColA = S.ColA** from update as these columns are already having the same value.

Comment: Hi Sonam, you're right, those can be removed but the results remain the same. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The target table, TableB, is empty.  Change this line:
Old:  INSERT INTO TableA VALUES  ( 'XXXXXXXX', NULL )
New:  INSERT INTO ***TableB*** VALUES  ( 'XXXXXXXX', NULL )